# Error: taking address of temporary

Tags: c++, pointers

I know that this question was already asked a lot but non of the answers could help me with my specific problem.

I get the famous "taking adress of temporary" error. And as far as I understood that's because I am trying to convert a temporary object to a pointer.

But does anyone here has a solution to how I can fix this here?

My code in that the error occurs is the following:

```
newGame = &MenuOption(optionNewGame, text_new_game.width, 2, 0);
```

The declaration of newGame looks like this:

```
MenuOption *newGame;
```

An the error looks like this:

```
1>  c:/path/to/project/MainMenu.h:27:65: error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]
1>     newGame = &MenuOption(optionNewGame, text_new_game.width, 2, 0);
1>                                                                   ^
```

Comment: Well, the solution is "don't do that". Why not just `MenuOption newGame`?

Comment: There's not enough context. The solution is to not take the address of a temporary, but there isn't enough information to suggest a working alternative.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ Taking address of temporary - error while assigning reference to pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9263444/c-taking-address-of-temporary-error-while-assigning-reference-to-pointer)

Comment: Which *framework* are you using? This is important to decide if it's possible to create a new `MenuOption`

Comment: @BoBTFish I need to pass my object as a pointer parameter to another function, and it didn't work that way.

Comment: @Wolf What do you exactly mean by _framework_ in that case? I coded all the functions and classes myself.

Comment: @StuntHacks Okay, asked differently: where is "MenuOption" declared? Or: where did you find the documentation (help) of the class?

Comment: @Wolf Well, I wrote the entire class myself so there isn't really a documentation of it.

Comment: Just to be sure to understand you right: You wrote the `MenuOption` class? In that case you should know how to use it, I'm a little bit confused now...

Comment: Yes, I wrote it. And it works when using just a object created from it. But I need to pass different child classes of the `MenuOption` to a function and thus I have to pass an array containing all these objects.

Comment: @StuntHacks Well, then you have to provide more information to get the problem solved and/or a good (or at least acceptable) question from this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a temporary object of your `MenuOption` class. Then you store the address of this temporary object in `newGame`. Once the control block is left, the temporary object will be deleted and your pointer becomes a 'dangling pointer'.

Solutions:

- `MenuOption newGame(optionNewGame, text_new_game.width, 2, 0);`
- `newGame = new MenuOption(optionNewGame, text_new_game.width, 2, 0);`
- use `unique_ptr`:
  `std::unique_ptr< MenuOption> newGame;`
  `newGame.reset( new MenuOption(optionNewGame, text_new_game.width, 2, 0));`

Comment: The second option needs a type specifier. The options have to be multiplied with the scope options (global, member, local)

Comment: What do you mean? My second option corresponds to the OP's question, where the declaration and definition of `newGame` are separated: `MenuOption *newGame; newGame = new ...`

Comment: Provided all options contain a proper type specifier, which is true for (1) and (3), `MenuOption* ` is missing before `newGame` in (2).